# IIS7 Rewrite Module and ASP.net Request.PhysicalPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've been tasked with creating a bread crumb functionality for a client.  Their current website is setup to be XML/file based.  Each .aspx page is N levels deep with an  control hooked up to its respective .xml file.

I've decided to implement the bread crumbs via the pages directory structure.  I'm grabbing the physical path, stripping the root, splitting the directories, and using the parts as my breadcrumb.  All of their folders are named in CamelCase, so I am using the camel casing to break up the word for display purposes.

e.g:  Site may look like

Home

-- SubDir 1

------ SubDir 1.1

---------- MyPage.aspx

-- SubDir 2

------ MySecondPage.aspx

If you are on "MyPage.aspx".. the breadcrumbs you get are:

Home -> Sub Dir 1 -> Sub Dir 1.1 -> My Page

Here's the issue I am having.  The client is also using IIS7 Rewrite Module to enforce lower-case URLs.  The problem with this, is that the value I get back in my Request.PhysicalPath call is all lowercase, so my display text does not work (because it is relying on CamelCase).  If I turn off the IIS7 enforcement, it displays as above.  If not, I'll get:

Home -> subdir 1 -> subdir 1.1 -> mypage

Is there anyway to enforce lower-case URLs via the IIS7 Rewrite module **without** affecting the Request.PhysicalPath (or Request.PhysicalApplicationPath) calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot rely on Request.PhysicalPath in this case.

Try using [approach from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325931/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows-with-net) for getting actual file name in proper casing

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for, you da best.  As a follow up question, because this implementation will be used to build breadcrumbs and therefore called on a per-page basis, what do you think the repercussions will be for accessing the I/O at least a few times per loop, iterate through the loop at least a few times (n times for n deep directory levels), every page load?

Comment: Is it worth adding a caching mechanism to cache the formatted path info and use that value instead of going to the file system each time?

Comment: It is difficult to predict perfomance without tests. However, in similar cases (when results are not expected to change over time) I usually use static ConcurrentDictionary or HttpApplicationState to store results, it is easy to implement and guarantees that there are no reduntant I/O.

Comment: Good call @Artem, that's exactly what I ended up doing and it's working great in production