# sharpsvn Commit fails with missing item

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I am trying to use SharpSvn to programatically commit my working copy changes to a repository. Unfortunately, I receive the following error message: "Error during commit: 'SomeFile' is scheduled for addition, but is missing." (please note that I removed the path of the file here). The file is existing and if I use TortoiseSVN to commit the changes, everything works as expected.

My code for commiting:

```
// use throw on error, since it provides more information why the operation failed
            // might slow down a little bit, because of the exception handling
            SvnCommitArgs commitArgs = new SvnCommitArgs() { ThrowOnError = true, Depth = (SharpSvn.SvnDepth)depth, LogMessage = logMessage };
            List<Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>> committedItems = new List<Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>>();
            SharpSvn.SvnCommitResult commitResult;

            using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
            {
                svnClient.Notify += (sender, notifyEventArgs) =>
                {
                    switch (notifyEventArgs.Action)
                    {
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitReplacedWithCopy:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.ReplacedByCopy));
                            break;
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitAddCopy:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.CopyAdded));
                            break;
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitReplaced:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.Replaced));
                            break;
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitDeleted:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.Deleted));
                            break;
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitAdded:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.Added));
                            break;
                        case SvnNotifyAction.CommitModified:
                            committedItems.Add(new Tuple<string, SvnCommitItemChangeType>(notifyEventArgs.FullPath, SvnCommitItemChangeType.Modified));
                            break;
                    }
                };
                svnClient.Commit(itemPaths.ToList(), commitArgs, out commitResult);
            }
```

What I have noticed: The directory is written in UpperCases but the error messages show lower cases.

Edit:
The error message (log):
VictorSvnCore.DL.SvnCommitException: Error during commit: 'D:\TestManager\SysData\System' is scheduled for addition, but is missing ---> SharpSvn.SvnWorkingCopyPathNotFoundException: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnWorkingCopyPathNotFoundException: 'D:\Test\System' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at VictorSvnCore.DL.SvnClientFacade.Commit(IReadOnlyCollection`1 itemPaths, String logMessage, SvnDepth depth)

Comment: I solved the problem with these answer by using the exact path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/326153/3809520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SharpSvn is case sensitive it is necessary to use the exact path (as on the file system). I solved my problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326153/3809520), which allows to retrieve the exact path. Another possibility might be the `GetTruePath()` method from the `SvnTools` class by [SharpSvn](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnTools_GetTruePath.htm).