# How to get the actual file path with the original case in .Net Core on Windows (obviously)?

Tags: .net-core, filepath

The answers I know involve P/Invoke which I do not think is an option for .Net Core.

So how do we do it in .NET Core?

For example, consider `Path.GetFullPath("C:\AbC.txt")` it returns  "C:\AbC.txt", but the actual file path could be "C:\abc.txt" OR  "C:\ABC.txt". I need to get the actual file path with the original case.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are File and Directory classes that will get you FileInfo and DirectoryInfo for specific fiels/directories. From there you can get pretty much any info on the files, including absolute path.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: **Why** do you need to do this?

Comment: Does it really matter? I have my reasons. But since you insist. For interacting with git, which is completely screwed up when it comes to case sensitivity on Windows. Some of its commands are case insensitive, yet some are case sensitive, despite the `core.ignorecase=true` setting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325931/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows-with-net

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh - thanks. So my question is a duplicate..