# boost::filesystem v3 - correct case of path

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Hi
Is there an efficient way of correct the case of an given windows path?

```
fs::path dir("c:/winDOWS"); --> C:/Windows?
```

(without Windows-API!)

Comment: Do you mean not using the windows-api even on windows, or do you mean using some abstracting library so that the code will run unchanged on other platforms?

Answer (score 2):

Without the windows api it's impossible to know that the correct case is. The common windows filesystems are case-insensitive and case preserving.

The windows api way to do this is [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I cannot agree. Right know I use the directory iterator of boost and do a case insensitive compare to validate if it's the same path... the source code runs on linux as well and I don't see any reason to use win api for that purpose...

Comment: Boost.Filesystem uses the Windows API as well, it only wraps it, and if there is no wrapper for a certain function, you should use that function directly.

Comment: According to the linked documentation: "..This function does not verify that the resulting path and file name are valid, or that they see an existing file on the associated volume...". So GetFullPathName is NOT correct answer! Got confused myself, so decided to let others know the current top answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Since I came here looking for the same thing I figured I would spare others a google.

An answer can be found [in this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74451/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows).

It is sadly not how to do it with boost instead using the Windows API. But at least it works which the API mentioned above does not.