# C++ windows fstream case sensitive

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm noticing that on Windows, file opening is case insensitive.

(ex. `fstream("text.txt")` will open regardless of the actual filename being: `Text.txt`)

How would I make this case sensitive instead? (The file not opening unless the filename also matches the proper case)

Comment: Does _wfopen behave the same? It is strange since NTFS is a case-sensitive fs.

Comment: I doubt `fstream` has functionality to do this for you. Instead, you can use filesystem operations to find out the real name of the file, and compare it to the file name you are looking for. For the first step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74451/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows

Comment: Case sensitivity is a volume policy, so it's probably best to respect it.  [This article](http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/02/understanding-case-sensitivity-in-windows-obcaseinsensitive-file_case_sensitive_search/) has a lot of good info.  If you really want to force case sensitivity, you can manually compare against the actual filename.

Comment: `fstream` uses Win32; while the NTFS file system supports case-sensitivity, Win32 does not .. so "Text.txt" and "tExT.txt" might be able to exist in the same directory on your NTFS volume, but when you call `fstream("text.txt");` it will only open 1 of the files. If you want to use case-sensitivity, you'll need to link against POSIX subsystems instead of the Win32 subsystem.

Comment: @txtechhelp And hop in your time machine back to 1999 first...

Comment: Can't make edits after 5 minutes :) .. but the answer @JonathanPotter posted can help you to check if a file name is not the one you want in a case-sensitive environment and without having to muck around with linking against separate libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Windows the file system API is generally case-insensitive, so the only way is to check the case of the filename yourself. For example,

```
bool open_stream_ci(const char* pszName, std::fstream& out)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA wfd;
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFileA(pszName, &wfd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ::FindClose(hFind);
        if (!strcmp(wfd.cFileName, ::PathFindFileNameA(pszName)))
        {
            out.open(pszName);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100625 ; NTFS does support case sensitivity, Win32 subsystems, however, do not .. so an NTFS volume can have case-sensitive files/folders, but reading it via a Win32 app (like Notepad) will only open 1 of the files due to the case-insensitive nature of Win32 subsystem

Comment: @txtechhelp It's a bit meaningless to say NTFS supports it but Win32 doesn't. Where else do you use NTFS in real life?

Comment: On my samba shares and other Linux systems that support NTFS

Comment: @txtechhelp Touche. Presumably the OP is actually writing Win32 apps, however, or they would not have asked this question.