# Python - Getting actual file name (with proper casing) on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I want to do exactly the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74451/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows):

> Windows file system is case insensitive. How, given a file/folder name (e.g. "somefile"), I get the actual name of that file/folder (e.g. it should return "SomeFile" if Explorer displays it so)?

But I need to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the absolute path (like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325931/getting-actual-file-name-with-proper-casing-on-windows-with-net) for .NET), use:

```
from pathlib import Path

correct_casing = Path('path/to/file').resolve()
```

If you want a relative path when that is what was given, take the last `n` characters of that result:

```
from pathlib import Path

def resolve_casing(filename):
    fullpath = str(Path(filename).resolve())
    first_index = len(fullpath) - len(filename)
    return fullpath[first_index:]
```

Comment: The logic of `resolve_casing` doesn't hold up to an input `filename` that contains "." or ".." components, symlinks, or mountpoints. If you only need to normalize names, use ctypes or PyWin32's win32file module to call `GetLongPathName`, which walks the path forward calling `FindFirstFile` on each component. It preserves "." and ".." components, the use of slashes and backslashes, and doesn't resolve symlink or mountpoint components to their final path. The case of component names is normalized to the directory entry, and legacy 8.3 short names are replaced by the real (long) filenames.

Comment: Sounds like you have a better answer @ErykSun, please add it.

Comment: You're free to use it to re-implement `resolve_casing` for Windows. For example, for `p = r'spam/foo\bar1/..\bar2/.\test.txt'`, where "spam" and "test.txt" are symlinks, `win32file.GetLongPathName(p)` might yield a result like `r'Spam/fOO\Bar1/..\BAR2/.\test.TXT'`.

Comment: This answer seems to no longer work, .resolve() function does not resolve seem to resolve casing.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no access to a windows computer anymore. I never did try Eryk Sun's suggestion above, maybe that works? Please come back and answer this when you have figured it out.

Comment: @Kiraa Could you give an example where it doens't work?

Comment: Turns out it only does not work in certain cases, such as when .resolve() is applied to Google Drive path. No path to G:\ drive (where my Google Drive is mounted) is correctly capitalized after .resolve(). Method indeed still does work for 'physical' paths.